# Given odd positive integer, $n=2m-1$, $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies m \equiv 1 \pmod 2$

Tags: congruences

$n=2m-1\implies n+1=2m$.
 So, $n\equiv 1\pmod 4, 2m=n+1\equiv 2\pmod 4\implies 2m=n+1\equiv 0\pmod 2$ $\implies n\equiv -1\pmod 2\implies n\equiv 1\pmod 2$. 
But, how to find $m$ from this last line of equivalence relations is not clear.

Comment: If $n=1+4k$ then we have $4k+1=2m-1\implies 2m=4k+2\implies m=2k+1$.

Comment: $2m \equiv 2 \mod 4 \implies 4|2m - 2 \implies 2|m - 1\implies m \equiv 1 \mod 2$.  Or $2m = 2 + 4k$ so $m = 1 + 2k$ so $m \equiv 1 \mod 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n = 2m-1\equiv 1\pmod{4}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  2m \equiv 2\pmod{4}.$$
Now, note that in general, if $k\ne 0$ and $ak\equiv bk\mod{ck}$, this means that $ak$ is $bk$ plus a multiple of $ck$, say $rck$:
$$ak = bk + rck.$$
Dividing through by $k$ gives $a = b+cr$, so that $a\equiv b\mod c$. Applying this to $2m\equiv 2\mod{(4 = 2\cdot 2)}$ gives
$$m\equiv 1\pmod{2}.$$

Comment: But, then my approach is wrong as it must divide $2m$ by $2$, to get $m$, when dividing the modulus by $2$.

Comment: Remember $ak = bk \mod ck \implies a \equiv b \mod c$.  Your approach isn't wrong so much but in going from $2m \equiv 2 \mod 4$ to $2m \equiv 0 \mod 2$ you are simply throwing away information.

Comment: @fleablood Sorry, don't understand your comment. I never went to $2m\equiv 0\mod{2}$...

Comment: Oh, sorry rogerl.  That comment was meant to be a direct response to jitender's comment "But, then my approach is wrong as it must divide 2m by 2, to get m, when dividing the modulus by 2. "  Your method is just fine.  Although for the sake of the inexperience of the OP, it might be worth noting that $2m \equiv 2\mod 2*2 \implies m \equiv 2 \mod 2$ is valid and why.